# How to loop through choices in a cell on click?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to set up a quicker/easier attendance tracking google spreadsheet.  How do I make a cell loop through a series of options like: check mark or V, A, E, (blank)?  Similar to toggling a checkbox on and off.  I'm trying to avoid using a dropdown box because this needs to be fast as I call out student names, and easy for my other teachers, even on a tablet/phone.  All help is appreciated!

Tried Check boxes and dropdown boxes

Comment: Hey the question is not too clear. Can you provide a sample of your attendance tracker and the sample output you wish to achieve?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this approach, with a checkbox next to a dropbox. When the checkbox is ticked TRUE, then it will grab the next value of the dropdown (looping back to the beginning if it's the last value). It works both for Value in List and Value in Range:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cell = e.range;
  var modifiedValue = cell.getValue();

  if (modifiedValue === true) {
    
    var nextCell = cell.offset(0,1)
    
    // Get data validation rules for the current cell
    var rules = nextCell.getDataValidations();
    var rule = rules[0][0];
    // If the current cell has data validation
    if (rule != null && ( rule.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE || rule.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_LIST)) {
      var valuesRange = rule.getCriteriaValues()[0];
      if(rule.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE ) {
        valuesRange = valuesRange.getValues().map(n => n[0]).filter(n => n!="");
      }
      Logger.log(valuesRange)
      var currentDropdownValue = nextCell.getValue();
      // Find the index of the current value in the array
      var currentIndex = valuesRange.indexOf(currentDropdownValue);
      // Calculate the index for the next value, looping back to the beginning if necessary
      var nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % valuesRange.length;
      // Set the next dropdown value
      nextCell.setValue(valuesRange[nextIndex]);
    }

    // Set the current cell back to FALSE
    cell.setValue(false);
  }
}
```

[image]